# Transform Bitmap object into jagged array of RGB tuple values

Tags: image, f#

I've been working on this module with the assistance of codereview, and based on the responses and my own research, this is my project so far. The goal behind the code is that it starts with a .NET bitmap object, extracts the byte array of image data from the bitmap, then transforms it into an array of arrays or matrix.

The idea behind putting the bitmap data into the matrix is that I want to be able to use a simple representation of a coordinate, like Array[10][20], to get the RGB value for the pixel located at the (10, 20) coordinate. Rather than using a proper 2D array, I'm choosing to use an array of arrays, or "jagged" array, for speed concerns.

Your assistance with sanity, style, F# conventions, and any other problems you spot is appreciated in helping further refine this algorithm.

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Drawing.Imaging
open System.Runtime.InteropServices


module ImageSearch = 
    let LoadBitmapIntoArray (pBitmap:Bitmap) =
        let tBitmapData = pBitmap.LockBits( Rectangle(Point.Empty, pBitmap.Size), 
                                            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
                                            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb )  

        let tImageArrayLength = Math.Abs(tBitmapData.Stride) * pBitmap.Height
        let tImageDataArray = Array.zeroCreate<byte> tImageArrayLength

        Marshal.Copy(tImageDataArray, 0, tBitmapData.Scan0, tImageArrayLength)
        pBitmap.UnlockBits(tBitmapData)

        pBitmap.Width, tImageDataArray

    let Transform2D ( (pArrayWidth:int), (pArray:byte[]) ) = 
        let tHeight = pArray.Length / ( pArrayWidth * 3 ) // 3 bytes per RGB

        let tImageArray = [|
            for tHeightIndex in [ 0 .. tHeight - 1] do
                let tStart  = tHeightIndex * pArrayWidth
                let tFinish = tStart + pArrayWidth - 1 
                yield [|    
                    for tWidthIndex in [tStart .. 3 .. tFinish] do
                        yield ( pArray.[tWidthIndex]
                              , pArray.[tWidthIndex + 1] 
                              , pArray.[tWidthIndex + 2] )
                |]
        |]

        tImageArray

    let SearchBitmap (pSmallBitmap:Bitmap) (pLargeBitmap:Bitmap) = 

        let tSmallArray = Transform2D <| LoadBitmapIntoArray pSmallBitmap 
        let tLargeArray = Transform2D <| LoadBitmapIntoArray pLargeBitmap

        let mutable tMatchFound = false
```

Comment: *a square "jagged" array* <-- does not make much sense to me.... just saying.

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking about how to rephrase that. "An array of arrays where each array is the same length" maybe would work better?

Comment: 'matrix' may be a word that makes sense here.

Comment: It looks like your code has been cut off. `let mutable tMatchFound = false`, and then?

Comment: I haven't finished that part yet. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, F# function names are `camelCase`, for example `transform2D` instead of `Transform2D`.

---

[Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is dead and buried. For example, use `bitmap` instead of `pBitmap`.

---

If `ImageSearch` is a top-level [module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233221.aspx), declarations do not have to be indented.

---

Your `for...in` expressions can be written without brackets. For example, instead of

> ```
> for tHeightIndex in [ 0 .. tHeight - 1] do
> ```

write

```
for heightIndex in 0 .. height - 1 do
```

Similarly, instead of

> ```
> for tWidthIndex in [tStart .. 3 .. tFinish] do
> ```

write

```
for widthIndex in start .. 3 .. finish do
```

This is not just a style issue, the different versions actually compile to different IL.

---

The final expression of a function is its return value, so instead of

> ```
> let tHeight = ...
> let tImageArray = [| ... |]
> tImageArray
> ```

you can write

```
let height = ...
[| ... |]
```

---

<strike>In type annotations, it's conventional to have a space on either side of the `:`, for example instead of</strike>

> ```
> let Transform2D ( (pArrayWidth:int), (pArray:byte[]) ) =
> ```

write

```
let transform2D (width : int, array : byte[]) =
```

I can't actually back up this last point. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) and [FSharp.Core](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/set.fs) don't seem to stick to one style, even in the same function

> ```
> let isProperSuperset (x:Set<'T>) (y: Set<'T>) = SetTree.psubset x.Comparer y.Tree x.Tree
> ```

Comment: "This is not just a style issue, the different versions actually compile to different IL." What is the significance of the different way it compiles?

Comment: @KennethPosey it's the difference between a [sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) and a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx). One major difference is that a list must have all its elements in memory at once. As a silly example, try timing `printfn "%A" (Seq.length {0L .. 10000000L}` compared to `printfn "%A" (Seq.length [0L .. 10000000L])`.

Comment: so to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, the sequence option (using for-in-do without square brackets) is likely going to perform better than the list option when iterating?

Comment: I just ran it through `100000000L` for each of those two, and the sequence completed nearly instantly while the list hung for several seconds then overflowed. That answers my question then. Thanks a ton for the clarification.